# Access 2010 VBA - Open New Recordset - Values Unexpectedly Saved From Before Opening

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am having a script auto-detect if a user exists based on their last name and an identification number. If it exists within the database, the form is auto-completed with the correct data and will be updated upon saving. If not, a new record will be saved after the user enters in the rest of the data and pushes a save button.

The issue I am having is when the script auto-detects that a user DOES exist in the database, it saves the current data (being a last name and ID number) to the table, leaving all other fields blank.

My code:

```vb
Private Sub Last_AfterUpdate()

    Dim Check As Integer
    Dim records As Recordset
    Dim tmp As String
    Dim tmp1 As String
    Dim db As Database

    Set db = CurrentDb

    If Not IsNull(Me.ID) Then
        tmp = Me.ID
    End If

    If Not IsNull(Me.Last) Then
        tmp1 = Me.Last
    End If

    Set records = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * from [EmailList] WHERE ID1= '" & tmp & "' AND " & "Last = '" & tmp1 & "'")
    Me.Recordset.FindFirst "ID=" & records.Fields("ID")

End Sub
```

Note: There is a difference between fields `ID` and `ID1`. They are two forms of identification I use.

Comment: I feel like there is more to your code than what is here.  Where are you checking to see if the user already exists?   How are you automatically filling out the users' information?  What is the purpose of: `Set records = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * from [EmailList] WHERE ID1= '" & tmp & "' AND " & "Last = '" & tmp1 & "'")`?

Comment: @Ryan-w4588 not an answer to your question, but just a tip: at the end of this code you should close the recordset you've opened and remove the recordset and database from memory, so, respectively: `records.close`, `Set records = Nothing` and finally `Set db = Nothing`.

Comment: @MattHall I did know that, I'm still teaching myself to remember it in every script. Thanks! I'm about to look through all my files to make sure I did this haha. I appreciate the constructive criticism!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you are doing this in the `AfterUpdate` so the record is being created before you ever check to see if the user exists.  I think you want something more like this:

First a function to check if user exists:

```vb
Public Function UserExists(intID As Integer, strLastName As String) As Boolean
    'If user exists in EmailList Table
    If Nz(DLookup("Last", "EmailList", "Last = '" & strLastName & "' AND ID = " & intID), "") <> "" Then
        UserExists= True
    Else
        UserExists= False
    End If

End Function
```

Then in your `BeforeUpdate` event you want to do something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Last_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    'If user filled out both fields
    If Nz(Me.ID, "") <> "" And Nz(Me.Last, "") <> "" Then

        'If they exist in the database
        If UserExists(Me.ID, Me.Last) Then

           'Cancel saving record and go to the record with their information
           Cancel = True
           Me.Recordset.FindFirst "ID=" & records.Fields("ID")
        End If

    Else 'User didn't fill out both fields.
       MsgBox "You must fill out ID and Last field"
    End If

End Sub
```

This is rough coding but I feel like this is the direction you will want to take to accomplish what you are looking for.  Logic will need to be adjusted for your situation.

Comment: Should your `UserExists` function make use of the `intID` argument somewhere?

Comment: It most certainly should, thanks for spotting that. :-)